# Stuck trying to list associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I think I am deeply misunderstanding how to write instances.

Miniatures have_many Manufacturers through the Productions table.

On the miniatures show page I am trying to list all the manufacturers for the current miniature and have them link the Manufacturer show page. Like so:

```
<% @miniature.manufacturers.each do |manufacturer| %>
    <%= link_to @miniature.manufacturer.name, manufacturer_path %>
<% end %>
```

Needless to say it does not work. It gives "undefined method `manufacturer'".

I have tried A LOT of different combinations to no avail. The following version puts all the manufacturers, rolled into one link, once for each manufacturer a miniature has, and links to /manufacturers. A big mess.

```
<% @miniature.manufacturers.each do |manufacturer| %>
    <%= link_to @miniature.manufacturers.map(&:name).join(', '), manufacturer_path %>
<% end %>
```

I have been working on other things and hoping I would get the hang of this but I'm pretty sure it's something pretty fundamental about how I set up the instance.

If it's more likely something I need to add to the controller then I can add my controller code here. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
<% @miniature.manufacturers.each do |manufacturer| %>
    <%= link_to manufacturer.name, manufacturer_path(manufacturer) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: OH BOY. Yes. Yes, it does. I thought I'd tried all the simple things and they'd failed. I hadn't. Thank you SO much. Why is it that I've always overcomplicated it? Bless you Benjamin Tan and bless you the simplicity of Rails.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Don't give up! :)

Comment: Can you explain why the same trick doesn't work on my miniatures index page?

Comment: How does your `MininaturesController` look like and your view?

Comment: Have opened another question so as not to clutter and to properly reward the answer. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690340/linking-to-associated-models-in-index-view