# Linking to associated models in INDEX view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Just solved the problem of linking to associated models in my SHOW view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689585/stuck-trying-to-list-associated-model/19689612?noredirect=1#comment29245549_19689612) but the same answer doesn't work for my INDEX view.

What I'm trying to make work, and can't is the Manufacturer bit, which is a model that belongs_to Miniatures. The table comes out fine but I can't get the manufacturer to display and link properly. Sorry this wasn't clear.

My miniatures **index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All miniatures') %>
<h1>All miniatures</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<table border="0" cellpadding="10">
<th align="left">Name</th>
<th align="left">Material</th>
<th align="left">Manufacturer</th>
<th align="left">Scale</th>
<th align="left">Product Code</th>
<th align="left">Sculpted by</th>
<th align="left">Release date</th>
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %><th align="left">Admin</th><% end %>
  <%= render @miniatures %>
</table>

<%= will_paginate %>

<h1> Import Miniatures</h1>

<%= form_tag import_miniatures_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Which renders this **partial** to display the miniatures:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %></td>  
  <td><%= miniature.material %></td>
  <td><%= link_to manufacturer.name, manufacturer_path(manufacturer)</td> 
  <td>scale</td> 
  <td><%= miniature.pcode %></td>
  <td>sculptor</td>
  <td><%= miniature.release_date %></td>
  <td><% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", miniature, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %></td></tr>
```

I can see that it can't work just the same as my view because there I had a named instance `|manufacturer|` that I don't have here. I guess then that I need to define it in the controller? Under Index?

Here is my (slightly cropped) **MiniaturesController**

```
class MiniaturesController < ApplicationController
       before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
       before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

       def import
         Miniature.import(params[:file])
         redirect_to root_url, notice: "Miniatures imported."
       end

      def show
        @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @miniature = Miniature.new 
        @miniature.productions.build
        @miniature.sizes.build
        @miniature.sculptings.build
      end

      def create
        @miniature = Miniature.new(miniature_params)
        @production = @miniature.productions.build
        @size = @miniature.sizes.build
        @sculpting = @miniature.sculptings.build
        if @miniature.save
          redirect_to @miniature
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def edit
        @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])

      end

      def update
        @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
         if @miniature.update_attributes(miniature_params)
          flash[:success] = "Miniature updated"
          redirect_to @miniature and return
        end
         end
       end
     end
          render 'edit'
      end

      def index
        @miniatures = Miniature.paginate(page: params[:page])
      end

      def destroy
        Miniature.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "Miniature destroyed."
        redirect_to miniatures_url
      end

    private
        def miniature_params
          params.require(:miniature).permit(:name, :release_date, :material, :pcode, :notes, productions_attributes: [:id, :manufacturer_id, :miniature_id], sizes_attributes: [:id, :scale_id, :miniature_id], sculptings_attributes: [:id, :sculptor_id, :miniature_id])
        end

        def admin_user
          redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
        end

        def signed_in_user
          unless signed_in?
            store_location
            redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
          end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change your controller. The relationship between miniature and manufacturer should have been defined at the model level, e.g.:

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end

class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :miniatures
end
```

Your actual relation code may differ, but the above demonstrates the principles.

In your miniature partial (`miniatures/_miniature.html.erb`), a miniature's manufacturer is available as an attribute:

```
<td><%= link_to miniature.manufacturer.name, miniature.manufacturer %></td>
```

(NB: note you can include the object instance, and Rails' routing helpers will automatically convert it into the appropriate path, assuming you've specified `resources :manufacturers` in your routes.rb file).

I get the feeling you're struggling a bit with the way ActiveRecord associations work, and end up confusing yourself as a result.

Comment: I am struggling but it seems to me that the simple things, like the above, don't work. When I put the code you've got here in, I get "undefined method `manufacturer' for #<Miniature". The models have both as has_many through relationships. Miniature has many Manufacturers through Productions and Manufacturers have many Miniatures through Productions. That ought to be okay right?